How to choose a specific commit to undo on a branch
Suppose we have a commit tree that looks like this:
A -> B -> C -> D -> E

Where each of A, B, ..., E are commits. Further, suppose commit B has a change that I now want to completely reverse. More specifically, I want to make the commit tree look like this:
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> (E - B)

Here, I mean for E - B to denote the commit that is identical to commit E, only with the changes from commit B reversed---i.e. if commit B deletes a line from a file, then that line is inserted back in, and vice versa. Is there an easy way to do this? Ideally I would like something like git cherry-pick undo [commit].
P.S. I ask this partly because I was taught that it's best to think of a git commit as an action done on your codebase, which is why you're supposed to write git commits like "Update file" rather than "Updated file." With that in mind, it made sense to me that you can undo any action done on your codebase.

Reversed or erased from the commits on the brsnch? Reversing a commit creates an opposite change.

You're basically searching for git revert B. It will create a new commit on top with the inverse changes brought by B, like a negative cherry-pick. Take a look at the doc.

The answer to your question can be found at: How to use Git Revert. If you disagree, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
